# Credential manager for Vista/Windows 7

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi, 64-bit, winlogon

I have Credential manager implemented in VC++ which captures credentials during login process. It works well in XP/Vista/Windows 7 32 bit env. But is not working in 64 bit.
Any idea ?
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Please clarify "not working". Is it being called but functioning correctly, or is not being invoked at all, for instance?

Comment: Initially dll was not being invoked at all, but after compiling dll for X64 , its being invoked, but now i m not reaching to  NPLogonNotify implementaion of dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your DLL to be loaded by a 64-bit process, your DLL has to be compiled for 64 bits.

If you want your DLL to be loaded by a 32-bit process, your DLL has to be compiled for 32 bits.  This is true on both 64-bit Windows systems and 32-bit Windows systems.

John gave you a useful link, even though John's wording is wrong.  An application (exe) which is built for 32 bits will run in 64 bit Windows, but it can only load 32-bit DLLs.

Comment: Agreed, I have compiled it for 64 bit and the dllmain gets called at winlogon (Verified by putting logs). But now the problem is I am not receiving "NOLogonNotify" function (Which i get in 32 bit) at all..
Any thoughts ??????

Comment: You're probably missing some registry entries.  If a 32-bit app added registry entries then the app probably put them in a WoW6432 node, which won't even be noticed by 64-bit apps.  You need to make sure they're in the correct location for ordinary 64-bit credential registrations.

Comment: Well, got it working, the problem was in runtime exception with calling convention. Thanks for you help for suggesting 32 bit dll vs 64 bit dll.

Answer (score -1):

Did you build for a 64-bit platform in Visual Studio?

A Visual C++ application which is build for a 32-bit environment won't work directly in a 64 bit environment. And although applications will work using the WOW64 compatibility layer, DLLs *must* be 64-bit if they are to be loaded by a 64-bit operating system.

Since that is indeed the case here, you need to build your project for a 64-bit platform (Visual Studio 2005 and later have a 64-bit compiler).

See the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185328.aspx for more details.

Comment: @John : I m pretty sure that application build for 32 bit env works for 64 bit using WOW64.